# Convert PSD file to INDD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, text

I have a text layout in Photoshop that is very precisely arranged. Is there a way to recreate this layout in InDesign without too much work?

Tips, tricks, scripts, are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know what you plan to do with it but you could always export out as a `.pdf` file and import the `.pdf` file into InDesign.  You really should have done all the typsetting in InDesign and note depending on the `.psd` quality it may render the text poorly in InDesign.  What I would do is export the `.pdf` file and place the it onto a layer and lock the layer after you have it positioned and re-create the text in InDesign.  It could be timely depending on the amount of type you have.